# SQL Full Text Search Problem

Tags: sql, full-text-search

What am I doing wrong with my full text search? If this code

```
Select UserID, UserName
From Users
Where Contains([UserName], '%Jack%')
```

I get the user jack back, but if I do this

```
Select UserID, UserName
From Users
Where Contains([UserName], '%Ja%')
```

I get nothing what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing LIKE syntax with CONTAINS. Keep in mind that full text searching is word based, while like searches for a character pattern within a string.

Try:

```
Select UserID, UserName
From Users
Where Contains([UserName], '"Ja*"')
```

Comment: Whats the best way to implement a search then? Using Fulltext or Like, because I want the users to be able to search 6 different columns and if any of them match return the row.

Comment: Fulltext will be much faster, assuming you're searching for words or prefixes of words. If you're trying to find snippets of characters (e.g., 'rv' in 'server') then you'll need to rely on Like.

Answer (score 0):

`Contains([UserName], '"Ja*"')` - Syntax for PREFIX search. Would match "Jack" but NOT "Ajax"

You cannot do any POSTFIX search with full text search. If you were to try:

```
Contains([UserName], '"*Ja*"') -- wrapped in *
```

This would actually still do a PREFIX ONLY search, it will strip out all special characters that are not proper syntax, meaning the first * would be stripped then ran. If you need open ended search you need to use %% still to find inner parts or words.